# C++ Manually extending generated code with safe names

Tags: c++, code-generation, naming

A project of mine generates C++ code. Now I want to be able to extend the generated code with C++ code. The generated code uses a guard for each generated name (e.g. "d393jkdd").
So a generated class could look like:

```
namespace d393jkdd_utils {
    class d393jkdd_Math {
    public:
         static double PI;
    };
}
```

Now let's say I want to be able to use this class in a handwritten piece of C++ code.
Of course I could define a macro for this. But I would like to know if there are better and cleaner solutions. Because it must also be possible to manually write a function body of a generated prototype.

Comment: Why not just use namespaces ?

Comment: Because there are a a lot of standard (built-in) identifiers/keywords/etc in C++ which will be used for different cases. Besides there are some complicated situations where standard naming will not work.

Comment: "identifiers/keywords/etc" covers a lot of ground. If you use a namespace (such as `d393jkdd_utils`) you don't need to mangle names that are defined inside the namespace unless they're keywords, in which case you've probably got a design error. This is **exactly** the kind of thing that namespaces were design for.

Comment: @PeteBecker I also got a lot of wrappers around primitives, such as int/int32_t/size_t etc. And that is causing problems.

Comment: Shrug. Handwaving won't get you meaningful answers. Show some code.

Comment: @PeteBecker I just don't want the language being relying on the design of C++. So one may write "Int int" if he/she likes to. Besides, these are just simple examples. The problem comes bigger with more complicated situations as custom template functions, which are in my case not the same as the ones in C++. So those should have their own identifier which may not be accesible by generated code, but should be accessible by C++ itself for containing the function body.